# Outlook 365 Inbox does not sync unless restarted or manually pressing "Update Folder" in the send/receive tab

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, office365, microsoft-outlook-2016

Outlook 365 inbox does not sync (i.e. does not show new emails) unless it is restarted or I manually press the "update folder" button in the send/receive tab. I already tried the followings but could not fix the problem:

1. Removing `.ost` and cached files
2. Recreating outlook profile
3. Reinstalling office 365

Weird thing is, Outlook syncs my inbox folder fine when my laptop is connected to the internet via a wired connection; the problem only occurs when it is connected via WiFi. Also, I am using a University account to connect to their Exchange Server.

I see some people suggesting to turn off the cached mode, but I do not want to turn off this feature. There are many people having the [same issue](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/e5a23fb2-0007-4aa3-9ab0-b2664c06b821/outlook-cached-mode-not-updating-folders-from-exchange?forum=outlook), but I could not find the proper solution to this.

Comment: When connecting via WiFi, can you receive new emails timely on OWA?
Does Outlook show "connected to Exchange" in the status bar?

Answer (score 0):

After couple of re-installations of office 365, the outlook started working with wifi. I really don't know what caused the problem. I will update if it does not sync emails again...

Comment: Most likely, there were a few Outlook settings misconfigured.  If it occurs again, you'll want to review the following: File > Options > Advanced > Send/Recieve...